Auto update APK android API 30 : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /file:/storage/emulated/0/Download
I'm trying to auto update an android application with an url but I'm getting the error :  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /file:/storage/emulated/0/Download
I follow this answer FileProvider - IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root  but the error is still here
I'am using Java android with sdk 30
here is my code
    public void downloadFile(final Activity activity, final String url) {
        try {
            if (url != null && !url.isEmpty()) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                activity.registerReceiver(new MainDownloadCompleteReceiver(), new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS.toString(), "myfile.apk");
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Please insert an SD card to download file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    public class MainDownloadCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                openDownloadedAttachment(context, downloadId);
            }
        }

        private void openDownloadedAttachment(final Context context, final long downloadId) {
            DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
            query.setFilterById(downloadId);
            Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                @SuppressLint("Range") int downloadStatus = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
                @SuppressLint("Range") int fileSize = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));
                @SuppressLint("Range") String downloadLocalUri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                @SuppressLint("Range") String downloadMimeType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_MEDIA_TYPE));

                if ((downloadStatus == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) && downloadLocalUri != null) {
                    openDownloadedAttachment(context, downloadLocalUri, downloadMimeType);
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }

        /**
         * Used to open the downloaded attachment.
         * <p/>
         * 1. Fire intent to open download file using external application.
         *
         * 2. Note:
         * 2.a. We can't share fileUri directly to other application (because we will get FileUriExposedException from Android7.0).
         * 2.b. Hence we can only share content uri with other application.
         * 2.c. We must have declared FileProvider in manifest.
         * 2.c. Refer - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html
         *
         * @param context            Context.
         * @param attachmentPath      Uri of the downloaded attachment to be opened.
         * @param attachmentMimeType MimeType of the downloaded attachment.
         */
        private void openDownloadedAttachment(final Context context, String attachmentPath, final String attachmentMimeType) {
            if(attachmentPath!=null) {
                try {
                    File file = new File(attachmentPath);
                    Uri attachmentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "myapplication.provider", file);
                    Intent openAttachmentIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
                    openAttachmentIntent.setDataAndType(attachmentUri, attachmentMimeType);
                    openAttachmentIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    openAttachmentIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(openAttachmentIntent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "cannot open file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

And my AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HID_DEVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/img_20230611_wa0005"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/img_20230611_wa0005"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="s">

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="myapplication.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_path" />
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

and my file_path.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>

Here is the full stack trace
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /file:/storage/emulated/0/Download/myfile.apk 
at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:825)
at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:450)
at MainActivity$MainDownloadCompleteReceiver.openDownloadedAttachment(MainActivity.java:413)
at MainActivity$MainDownloadCompleteReceiver.openDownloadedAttachment(MainActivity.java:388)
at MainActivity$MainDownloadCompleteReceiver.onReceive(MainActivity.java:371)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1556)
at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2)at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

If anyone has an idea to fix the error.
Thank you
